# T-SQL CONVERT datetime to varchar using style 20 vs 120

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I see no difference between the *style* translation of `20` versus `120`. From what I've read, it seems there should be no difference.

Per the [CAST and CONVERT documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), it's noted:

> The default values (0 or 100, 9 or 109, 13 or 113, 20 or 120, and 21
>   or 121) always return the century (yyyy).

As you can see they do return the same result:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 20) AS 'exampleOne'
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 120) AS 'exampleTwo'
```

[image]

---

Why are there two *style* translation options and which should I use going forward? If it's completely optional (user preference) that is a fine answer too, I am just curious because I've seen both instances used in our code and I wonder what the reasoning was behind the additional *style* value. In the documentation, you can see that there are a few instances where multiple values can be used for the optional *style* argument.

Comment: in general style less than 100 is without century. I think those stated are the exception case

Comment: Back before year 2000 the old school 20 or 21 let you mimic old SQL CAST behavior and only show 2 digit years.  Useful in a lot of text based interface scenarios where we were trying to maintain 2 digit year compatibility with old stuff.  10  110   11 111  were common so those others may have been added after 10 and 11 and so never supported the 2 digit year ever.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already read from the documentation: there is no difference. I think that MS has provided both possible values just because in all other cases, also two values are possible (x and 100+x).